# Redirect user when hardware back button is pressed in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, redirect

I have an Ionic 5 app and I want to redirect the user to a specific page if he presses the hardware back button when a condition is met. (I want that feature only in one of my pages)
Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Create a service for that , and create two functions, one with your condition, and the second with normal back navigation proccess using ionrouteroutlet.pop(); and then in all constructors in pages, add this function and by default if condition is met then it will do its function and if not will do normal back function. Note: if you want to get the current route name from service, use router.events.subscribe ((event: RouterEvent) => {...});

Comment: `this.subscription = this.platform.backButton.subscribe(()=>{
          this,router,navigate(['/yourPageRoute'])
      });`